# PHP file always ends in 404 object not found

Tags: php, object, http-status-code-404

If I open up this php page with my localhost (XAMPP Apache Server) I always end up in a "404 object not found" screen. 
I tried to display text with echo but can't get any output... I always end up in the 404 object not found screen and can't explain to me why.

Here my code:

```html
<?php
header("location: add/Project.html" );

 $handle = fopen("Project.html", "a");
 foreach($_POST as $value ) {

 fwrite ($handle, $value);
 }
 fclose($handle . "\n");

exit;
?>
```

Any ideas ?
Every help is highly appreciated!
Thanks alot guys !

Comment: what is the base url for your site?

Comment: even if I try to open the php file directly by clicking it the 404 object not found appears...

Comment: that first line redirects the script, the rest wont run

Comment: the sens behind all is that I submit a form and trigger this php file with action="server.php". The php file creates a html file where the input of my textarea gets written in.

Comment: header as the last thing then, you can delete the `exit;`

Comment: @delboy1978uk thanks ! removing the first line worked for me! I need to create the project.html by my self and just keep it than .

Comment: you can check if file_exists and if not create it, if so open it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You redirect on the first line. Get rid of that! If you do need the redirection, add it at the end!

```
<?php


 $handle = fopen("Project.html", "a");
 foreach($_POST as $value ) {

 fwrite ($handle, $value);
 }
 fclose($handle . "\n");

 header("location: add/Project.html" );
```